# Why THREAD-1 and THREAD-2 do not interleave?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    public class Mutex {

private int val;
public Mutex(int val) {

    this.val=val;
}

public int getVal() {
    return val;
}

public void printVal()
{
    int i=0;
    while (true)
    {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+this.getVal());
        if(i==50)
            break;
        else
            i++;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    final Mutex m1=new Mutex(1);
    final Mutex m2 = new Mutex(2);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            m1.printVal();

        }
    },"THREAD-1").start();
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            m2.printVal();

        }
    },"THREAD-2").start();
}


    }
```

When "val" is of type "int", THREAD-1 and THREAD-2 do not interleave while if I change it's type to double, the threads interleave. I understand primitives are thread safe (except long and double) . How exactly does this work considering the above codes sample?

Comment: When I run this code I do see the interleaving, regardless of the data type.

Comment: printVal() is too quick that you cannot be sure if it will even require interleaving or not, for looping 50 times. make it much more and then try.

Comment: use System.nanoTime() to see how long the threads take to do their *work*. Maybe it does not make ssense to context-switch in such a short time. Useful times for threading experiments start at one millisecond at least.

Comment: @ay89  and Ralf H yes, increasing the loop count does make the threads interleave irrespective of the data type. Thanks. I missed the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to increase 50 to 1000000, **maybe** then they will?
Thread 1 done executing before its time slot ended, so there was no context switch.

Or, ..., if you'll add a `Thread.sleep` every iteration, you'll probably find out the they do interleave.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are designed to run independently as possible.  If you wanted to calls to be made interleaved, you would use a loop calling each with one thread.

You should assume that your threads can start and stop at any point unless you control them.  For performance reasons it usually best to place only the minimum of controls on them or you could end up with a solution which is more complicated and slower, not faster, which is usually the point of using threads.